# string.punctuation not working as expected in python

Tags: python, string

I was trying to create a program that removes all sorts of punctuation from a given input sentence. The code looked somewhat like this

```
from string import punctuation
sent = str(input())
def rempunc(string):
    for i in string:
        word =''
        list = [0]
        if i in punctuation: 
            x = string.index(i)
            word += string[list[-1]:x]+' '
            list.append(x)
    list_2 = word.split(' ')
    return list_2
print(rempunc(sent))
```

However the output is coming out as follows:

```
This state ment has @ 1 ! punc.

['This', 'state', 'ment', 'has', '@', '1', '!', 'punc', '']
```

Why isn't the punctuation being removed entirely? Am I missing something  in the code?

I tried changing x with x-1 in line 7 but it did not help. Now I'm stuck and don't know what else to try.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `word` and `list` variables?

Comment: `string[list[-1]:x]` starts at the last index where you found some punctuation, so you never remove anything. Note that using a list to keep track of the previous index is very clumsy, just use a variable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string for efficient ways to remove punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated string slicing isn't necessary here.

I would suggest using `filter()` to filter out the undesired characters for each word, and then reading that result into a list comprehension. From there, you can use a second `filter()` operation to remove the empty strings:

```py
from string import punctuation

def remove_punctuation(s):
    cleaned_words = [''.join(filter(lambda x: x not in punctuation, word))
                        for word in s.split()]
    return list(filter(lambda x: x != "", cleaned_words))
    
print(remove_punctuation(input()))
```

This outputs:

```py
['This', 'state', 'ment', 'has', '1', 'punc']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can approach it in a more pythonic way. I would use instead the python functions `string`, `translate` and `maketrans`. Here's an example based on your question:

```
original_string = "This statement has@ 1 ! punc,"

remove_punc_string = string.translate(str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)
```

This [seems](https://favtutor.com/blogs/remove-punctuation-from-string-python) to be the fastest way to remove punctuation.